# If a doesn't divide b and a doesn't divide c, what are the necessary conditions for having "a doesn't divide (b+c)"?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Also if "a" is a prime, is there a specific condition or a useful property to use " a doesn't divide (b+c) ?

Comment: The statement "$a$ does not divide $b+c$" is, by definition, equivalent to "$b\not\equiv-c\pmod a$". But that is true regardless of whether $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$, or of whether $a$ is prime. What type of condition are you hoping for?

Comment: Yes, if $a$ is prime  then $\bmod a\!:\, $ if $\,c\not\equiv 0\,$ then $\, b\not\equiv -c\iff b/c\not\equiv -1\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, you can say that $a$ does not divide $b+c$ if the sum of the remainders of the divisions $b:a$ and $c:a$ is not divisible by a.